# Convert angularjs directive to angular 10

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I want to use this code in my angular project:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Floating text animation (random)
 */
angular.module('g1b.text-animation', []).
directive('textAnimation', ['$document', '$interval', '$timeout', function ($document, $interval, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function () {
      return {
        pre: function () {},
        post: function (scope, element) {
          var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
          $interval(function () {
            for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); i++ ) {
              var character = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
              var duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
              var offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (45 - duration * 3)) + 3;
              var size = 12 + (15 - duration);
              var span = angular.element('<span class="animated-text" style="right:'+offset+'vw; font-size: '+size+'px; animation-duration:'+duration+'s">'+character+'</span>');
              element.append(span);
              $timeout(function (span) {
                span.remove();
              }, duration * 1000, false, span);
            }
          }, 250);
        }
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

it also has a CSS file with it.
this code is basically a text animation.
my problem is I don't know where to start.

this is what I'm trying to achieve:
https://rawgit.com/g1eb/angular-text-animation/master/

this is the npm of it:
https://github.com/g1eb/angular-text-animation

**Update:**

I've tried it on my own and this is what I have:

```
@ViewChildren('styleDiv', {read: ElementRef}) children: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private host: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.animateBackground();
  }

  private animateBackground(): void {
    const renderer = this.renderer;
    const children = this.children;
    const host = this.host;
    const chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
      'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
      '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); i++) {
        const character = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        const duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        const offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (45 - duration * 3)) + 3;
        const size = 12 + (15 - duration);
        const span = '<span class="animated-text" style="right:' + offset + 'vw; font-size: ' +
          +size + 'px; animation-duration:' + duration + 's">' + character + '</span>';
        this.children.first.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', span);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // renderer.removeChild(children.first.nativeElement.parentNode, children.first.nativeElement);
        }, duration * 1000, false, host, children, renderer);
      }
    }, 250, host, children, renderer);
  }
```

it works, but I do have a problem inside the set timeout function.
I'm able to add the span to the dom, but not able to remove it.

Comment: angular js and the current angular (2+) operate very differently, and I would not recommend trying to alter a package meant for angular js to fit.  Even if you managed to get the directive to work, the underlying css was most likely created under the assumption the resulting html generated from the directive would follow angularjs framework, needing significant rewrite to alter it to fit.  Probably better off trying to find an existing package for angular (2+) or writing one from scratch.

Comment: thx... I will try to write something from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After talking with the guy who wrote this directive we decided I would write a new directive for angular 2+ and he should approve the pull request in the next couple of days.
the new code should be available soon in his repository:
https://github.com/g1eb/angular-text-animation

but for now, here is the new directive:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[sbzTextAnimation]'
})
export class NgxSbzTextAnimationDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() maxFontSize = 20;
  @Input() colorSchemeArray: string[];
  @Input() position: 'left' | 'right' = 'right';

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.init();
    this.animateBackground();
  }

  private init(): void {
    this.colorSchemeArray = this.colorSchemeArray
      ? this.colorSchemeArray
      : [
        '#63b598', '#ce7d78', '#ea9e70', '#a48a9e', '#c6e1e8', '#648177', '#0d5ac1',
        '#f205e6', '#1c0365', '#14a9ad', '#4ca2f9', '#a4e43f', '#d298e2', '#6119d0',
        '#d2737d', '#c0a43c', '#f2510e', '#651be6', '#79806e', '#61da5e', '#cd2f00',
        '#9348af', '#01ac53', '#c5a4fb', '#996635', '#b11573', '#4bb473', '#75d89e',
        '#2f3f94', '#2f7b99', '#da967d', '#34891f', '#b0d87b', '#ca4751', '#7e50a8',
      ];
  }

  private animateBackground(): void {
    // need to access them in the setTimeout function
    const renderer = this.renderer;
    const elementRef = this.elementRef;

    const chars = [...Array(26)].map((e, i) => (i + 10).toString(36));

    setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); i++) {
        const duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        const offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (45 - duration * 3)) + 3;
        const size = 12 + (this.maxFontSize - duration);
        const color = this.colorSchemeArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colorSchemeArray.length)];

        const span = renderer.createElement('span');
        span.innerText = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        renderer.addClass(span, 'animated-text');

        renderer.setStyle(span, 'color', color);
        renderer.setStyle(span, this.position, `${offset}vw`);
        renderer.setStyle(span, 'font-size', `${size}px`);
        renderer.setStyle(span, 'animation-duration', `${duration}s`);
        renderer.setStyle(span, 'color', color);

        renderer.appendChild(elementRef.nativeElement, span);
        setTimeout(() => {
          renderer.removeChild(elementRef.nativeElement, elementRef.nativeElement.firstChild);
        }, duration * 1000, false, elementRef, renderer);
      }
    }, 250);
  }
}
```

I have also made some changes:

1. the text is now rainbow colors.
2. added an input for max font size to be customizable use case: [maxFontSize]="30"
3. added an input for rainbow colors. if the user only wants one color he can pass one
   color or different scheme like this:
   [colorSchemeArray]="['#000"]
4. added an input for the position of the floating text in the background.

this is the CSS for the directive (should be in the CSS file of the component using the directive):

```
/**
 * Floating text animation styles
 */
.animated-text {
  cursor: default;
  color: #68C2A3;
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  animation-name: float-animation;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes float-animation {
  0% {
    top: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: -25px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

here is a full working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/floating-text-animation?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Update:**
here is the link to the final directive on npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sbz-text-animation

Answer (score 1):

you can use a rxjs as well with scheduler which does smooth out the animation a little.

```
 interval(250)
   .pipe(
    // tap(_ => console.log("started..")),
    mergeMap(_ =>
      from([...Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))]).pipe(
        observeOn(asyncScheduler)
      )
    ),
    map(_ => this.getMap()),
    tap(({ span }) =>
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", span)
    ),
    mergeMap(({ duration }) =>
      of(null).pipe(
        delay(duration * 1000),
        tap(_ =>
          renderer.removeChild(
            this.elementRef.nativeElement,
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.firstChild
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    takeUntil(this._destroy$)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

added a method:

```
getMap(): { span: string; duration: number } {
  const character = this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)];
  const duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  const offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (45 - duration * 3)) + 3;
  const size = 12 + (this.maxFontSize - duration);
  const color = this.colorSchemeArray[
    Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colorSchemeArray.length)
  ];
  return {
    duration,
    span: `<span class="animated-text" style="color: ${color};${
      this.position
    }: ${offset}vw; font-size: ${size}px; animation-duration:${
     duration}s">${character}</span>`
};
```

}

make a subject _destory$ and OnDestroy method: to use in takeUntil to for garbage collection
the scheduler I used was `asyncScheduler` or `animationFrameScheduler`. `animationFrameScheduler` is better, but removal needs to be tweaked